# cannot set variable with localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]i use localstorage to store and access to my data in my function but only one of the variable is store and readable and the other is store but i don't know why i can store it (it's wortking when i reload the page). I saw my variable store in the debug panel in chrome

is store my data like this

```
 localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)); //data in json from API

 var obj = {
                    nom: user.nom,
                    prenom: user.prenom,
                    mail: user.mail,
                    username: user.username,
                    hasNewsletter : user.hasNewsletter,
                    coordonnee: user.coodonnee,
                    id: user.id
                };
  localStorage.setItem('userDatax', JSON.stringify(obj)); // data of an other API
```

this part of the code is in my main page

```
   this.state ={
      nfoUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),
      userDatax: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDatax'))
   }
//and i my render

console.log(this.state.userDatax, "user DATA") //NO DATA TILL RELOAD
console.log(this.state.nfoUser, "user vfo") // DATA
```

any idea ?

the picture show my localstorage just after localStorage.setItem

Comment: How are you setting the data in localStorage?

Comment: the one not working is set like that      var obj = {
                        nom: user.nom,
                        prenom: user.prenom,
                        mail: user.mail,
                        username: user.username,
                        hasNewsletter : user.hasNewsletter,
                        coordonnee: user.coodonnee,
                        id: user.id
                    };localStorage.setItem('userDatax', JSON.stringify(obj));                                                       and the other one              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

Comment: From what little you've shown, the code is fine. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one. Sadly, although Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) support React, including JSX ([here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)), they don't support local storage. So post the complete example here, and if you want to point to a live version, you'll have to point off-site (codepen.io. jsFiddle.net, etc.).

Comment: You probably might need to show when and where you are setting the `localStorage` items.

Comment: My guess is you are doing something asynchronously but try to read it synchronously. Impossible to tell with the code provided.

Comment: but i saw the data in my localstorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a timing problem.

If you JSON.stringify an object whose properties are undefined, you get an empty array:

```
var user = {nom: undefined};
console.log(JSON.stringify( user));
```

logs "{}".

This implies that the first API has not responded when localstorage is initially set with an `obj` derived from a `user` object that has no, or undefined, property values. Saying it works when the page is reloaded implies that at this time `user` has been updated, `obj` has been updated, and `localStorage` updated.

Beware that objects logged on the console can show property values that were updated after `console.log` was called. The exact effects can be hard to predict, but if you update local storage, and click the expand arrow on an existing log entry, you can see updated values in some cases.

To debug and see what local storage is at a particular time, convert it to a string before logging:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( localStorage), "debug message");
```